# How to change the color of the caret in a dropdown?

Tags: css

Is there any chance to change the color of the caret in a dropdown menu or `<select> option` using **CSS** like so ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to place a div over it with an image in that div.

```
<div>
    <img src="..." alt="" style="position:relative; top:...px; left:...px;" />
</div>
```

Place the div directly over the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

the *trick* is to change the `default style`,i.e is to use

```
select{
     -webkit-appearance:none;
        -moz-appearance:none;
        appearance:none;
}
```

More here [**styling-select-box-with-css3**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/styling-select-box-with-css3)

Comment: It removes the arrow. Do I need to replace it with an image? So there's no way on styling it using css only and image is excluded?

Comment: you have to use a label or image for that,check http://cssdeck.com/labs/styling-select-box-with-css3

Comment: @user3093453: for only using css try http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/